# NETSUITE CSV IMPORT - CUSTOMER PAYMENTS for INVOICES with INSTALLMENTS

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to import customer payments. I am trying to pay specific invoice numbers only per customer. It works for invoices with no installment. But for those with installments, the payment record is created but not applied to any invoice.

For my field mapping:
Internal ID > Customer Payment Invoices : Payment (Req)
Amount > Customer Payment Invoices : Invoice (Req)

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map this fields in you  CSV Import

[image: csv impor]